# Every time I try to run app bundle it overwrite on my android Manifest

Tags: android, flutter

I made a flutter app and every time I try to run app bundle it gives me an error and it writes the app name a second time alone. I don't understand why it does this, somebody has any solution? I also show the bundle.gradle in the next video:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tjKp.jpg

Android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.svapps.geografiebac.bacgeografie"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" /> <!-- Include required permissions for Advertising Id -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

    <application
        android:name="com.svapps.geografiebac.bacgeografie.10BacGeografie.10BacGeografie"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="bacgeografie" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.svapps.geografiebac.bacgeografie.10BacGeografie.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

            <!--
                 Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.storage.StorageRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.svapps.geografiebac.bacgeografie.flutter.image_provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/flutter_image_picker_file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="genericidp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="recaptcha" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.service.START" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.svapps.geografiebac.bacgeografie.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }


android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.svapps.geografiebac.bacgeografie"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2 // Change to a higher number
        versionName "2.0.1"
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}


flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    
   
}
```

I want to upload the app to google play console

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone corrects me if I am wrong, but Im pretty sure that the manifest you are looking at is generated for the release, the one that you should be editing and adding to is found under android/app/src/main.

The one you open in your video is under ../packaged_manifests/release/ (it will be overwritten with each build, based off the one found in android/app/src/main).

Comment: it gives me same error

Comment: https://imgur.com/NTUAwJu

Comment: The " <application" tag should be on line 4 below "package... " and above "android:version.."